# Detection of intersection between two $d$-dimensional convex polytopes with at most $N$ facets

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, cg.comp-geom, convex-geometry

I am looking for a reference on the current state-of-the-art algorithm(s) for detecting intersection between two $d$-dimensional convex polytopes, with time complexity depending on their number of facets (say, at most $N$).

I am aware of the [GJK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm), which is much more general, but can be used to detect intersection between convex polytopes in linear time in their number of *vertices.*

Is there a similar algorithm that detects intersection in linear time in the number of *facets* of the polytopes?

Importantly, I am not interested in *constructing* the intersection, but simply detecting whether it is nonempty.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to state how you are assuming the polytopes are specified (what representation you are using).